# How to cover both variants by regex?

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I have two possible variant values:

1. 9f3048c1-5c9a-462c-b284-db41231f8ab0
2. 9f3048c1-5c9a-462c-b284-db41231f8ab0.2

How to cover both values by a regex?
For the first, I have `[a-f0-9-]{36}`.
For the second I have `[a-f0-9-]{36}\.\d+`

But how to combine it?

I'm using it in Symfony project for like this:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex("/[a-f0-9-]{36}\.\d+/")
     */
    private string $reference;
```

Comment: Maybe `^[a-f0-9]{8}(?:-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8}(?:\.\d+)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the trailing dot and digit optional:

```regex
[a-f0-9-]{36}(?:\.\d+)?
```